# Google Cloud function send call to app hosted on GKE

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-kubernetes-engine

I would like to load data to my db hosted on GKE, using cloud function (small ETL needs, Cloud function would be great for that case)

I'm working in the same region. my GKE has an internal load balancer exposing an gcloud internal IP.

the method called is working perfectly when it's from Appengine but when doing it with cloud function I have an connexion error : "can't find client at IP"

I would like to know if it is possible ? 
if so, what would be the procedure ?

Many thanks !!

Gab

Answer (score 3):

We just released this feature to Beta. You can get started by following our docs:

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/connecting-vpc https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/connecting-vpc
https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible as of today.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36859738

> Thanks for your feedback.
>
> **You are totally right. At the moment the instances are only able to receive such requests via the external IP** [1].
>
> I have filed a feature request in your behalf so that this functionality might be considered for future deployments.  I cannot guarantee this will be implemented or provide an E.T.A. Nevertheless, rest assured that your feedback is always seriously taken.

We also reached out to our Google Cloud representative who confirmed this was a highly requested feature that was being looked at but was unable to provide an ETA as when it would be released.